# How do I access these elements of this JSON-encoded javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array in PHP that I encode to json:

```
$jsonOutput = json_encode($output);
```

Then in my javascript, I use this to parse it:

```
var jsonOutput    = JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonOutput; ?>');
```

My output looks like this in the Chrome console:

[image]

Ultimately, I have two arrays, and I'm trying to write a compare between the two to show if there are any items in the first array that aren't in the second, but I'm not sure how to reference `red` and `orange` here.

I tried `console.log(jsonOutput[0])` but I get `undefined`.

Also, as a side note, does anyone have any good resources for reading up on arrays in javascript and all their ins-and-outs?  It seems to be one aspect that I'm struggling with lately...

Comment: What does your PHP object look like?

Comment: You don't need to parse it with JS, since it's already JSON encoded: `var jsonOutput    = <?php echo $jsonOutput; ?>;` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your jsonOutput is an Object, so in order to access one member of the object you either have to user jsonOutput.red/jsonOutput.orange or jsonOutput["red"], jsonOutput["orange"] to access a member of the object.

More info here [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Comment: this linked article is a great resource.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonOutput.red[0]
```

You have an object with two keys.  Not an array.

Comment: is there a way for me to access those keys if I don't know their names beforehand though?

Answer (score 1):

You access those arrays using:

```
jsonOutput.red;
jsonOutput.orange;
```

Comment: The thing is though, I need to be able store whatever the name IS into a variable so that I can compare it against values from another array, (to see if `var1` contains items that `var2` doesn't.  I need to know how to access that... `location`, for lack of a better word, rather than the actual name directly (e.g. `red`, `orange`), which is why I was trying to use `[0]`

Comment: @JohnWu you can use `for (var key in jsonOutput) {`

Comment: hah.  I JUST got to that part in the thread linked by @Nicu Reut, and it works perfectly.  Thank you :)